# how can i save the file based on file path?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

i create browse button and it's show me what i want

this is my code

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog


root = tk.Tk()

label_list = []

def get_info(path):
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        pdf = PdfFileReader(f)
        info = pdf.getDocumentInfo()

        label_list[0].config(text=pdf.getNumPages())
        label_list[1].config(text=info.author)
        label_list[2].config(text=info.creator)
        label_list[3].config(text=info.producer)
        label_list[4].config(text=info.subject)
        label_list[5].config(text=info.title)

def browsefunc():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    pathlabel.config(text=filename)
    get_info(filename)

browsebutton = tk.Button(root, text="Browse", command=browsefunc)
browsebutton.pack()

pathlabel = tk.Label(root)
pathlabel.pack()

for i in range(6):
    label_list.append(tk.Label(root, text=""))
    label_list[i].pack()


root.mainloop()
```

and how can i save or move to new dir from file path browse button?

I really hope for your help

Comment: Have you ever searched for `python change directory`? There is a very nice module in Python that does offer this service.

Comment: yes, but nothing has changed @rioV8

Comment: you can't change the directory of the shell that is calling the program, you can launch a new shell in the directory you want.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to have the browse window open starting in a different directory location than where your python script is (the default behavior)?

If so, give the directory name as the parameter to `filedialog.askopenfilename()` like so:

```
# Example Directories 
# example_path = os.path.abspath('C:/Users/MyName/Desktop')
# example_path = os.path.abspath('C:/example/cwd/mydir/')
# or 

example_path = os.path.abspath('C:/Windows/Temp')
filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=example_path)
```

will open the file browser in that directory.